# Can I change the default parameters at the end

Tags: javascript, function

This code does not work. but is some way I can change only the last preset parameter?

```js
function test(a=1,b=2,c=3){
    console.log("abc"+a+b+c);
}

test(,,2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, pass `undefined` for the first two:

```js
function test(a=1,b=2,c=3){
    console.log("abc"+a+b+c);
}

test(undefined, undefined, 2);
```

The default parameter value is used if the effective value of the argument for that parameter is `undefined`. There are two ways that happens:

1. You didn't pass it at all (so it comes through as `undefined`), or
2. You pass `undefined` explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Pass `undefined`. For reference, [Passing_undefined_vs._other_falsy_values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Passing_undefined_vs._other_falsy_values)

```js
function test(a=1,b=2,c=3){
    console.log("abc"+a+b+c);
}

test(undefined, undefined,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this:

```
test(...[, , 2]);
```

Or this:

```
test(...Array(2), 2);
```

```js
function test(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) {
  console.log(a, b, c);
}
test(...[, , 2]);
test(...Array(2), 2);
```

Although explicitly passing `undefined` is more readable.